# How do i make a video's height the same as my window in html

Tags: html, css, size, height

I just wanna know how I make my video tag the same height as my window.
Here is what i have in my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="example video.mp4" id="video1">
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i have in my css file

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
#video1 {
    
}
```

Comment: you can use: `height: 100vh`

Comment: @MinalChauhan that gives me a tiny area at the bottom that is just white is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#video1 {
     display:block;
     height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#video1 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

By forcing the body to be the it's full height, we can make the video inside be the same height as well.